# Creating a custom reverse of list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm trying to create a custom reverse of list in Lisp. I'm pretty new to Lisp programming, and still struggling with syntax. This is my code so far

```
(defun new-union(l1 l2)
    (setq l (union l1 l2))
       (let (res) 
         (loop for x in l
           do(setq res (cons (car l) res))
           do(setq l (cdr l)))))
```

Here I'm taking two lists, and forming union list `l`. Then for reversing the list `l` I'm accessing element wise to append it to a new list `res`. Then consequently using the `cons`,  `car` and `cdr` to update the list. 
However, I'm getting a weird output. Can someone please suggest where I'm going wrong?

I'm aware of an inbuilt function for the same called `nreverse` , but I wanted to experiment to see how the Lisp interprets the data in list.

On printing `res` at the end, for example

```
(new-union '(a b c) '(d e f))
```

the output for above call gives me

```
(L A A A A A A A X X)
```

I think I'm doing the looping wrong.

Comment: Are you implementing reverse or union?

Comment: @coredump I'm taking the union of two list, and then reversing them.

Comment: You never return res. The result is the value of the last expression evaluated, here loop, which produces no value through an accumulating clause or a finally clause. The loop...do idiom is eq. to a dolist here, btw.

Comment: Also, you call setq on L, which is bad: L should probably be a local variable, declared with let, like res.

Comment: I have made some edits. and printed res. I'm getting the output as i have update now

Comment: okay. i also used `let` for L.. but there has been no change as such. i'm still getting the same output

Comment: You modify L while iterating on it: at best you skip every other element of the list, but this is dangerous: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Issues/iss240_w.htm

Comment: but i need the L to be destructive right ? for `car` the next element from L for appending it to `res` .. i'm kinda new to lisp so still not aware of the complications.

Comment: loop already iterates over L, you need only modify res by pushing each successive x in front of it. You are almost there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems

*(summary of previous comments)*

1. Bad indentation, spaces, and names; prefer this:

   ```
   (defun new-union (l1 l2)
     (setq list (union l1 l2))
     (let (reversed) 
       (loop for x in list
             do (setq res (cons (car list) reversed))
             do (setq list (cdr list)))))
   ```
2. Usage of SETQ on undeclared, global variables, instead of a LET
3. Mutation of the structure being iterated (LIST)
4. Not using X inside the LOOP (why define it?)
5. The return value is always NIL

### Refactoring

```
(defun new-union (l1 l2)
  (let ((reverse))
    (dolist (elt (union l1 l2) reverse)
      (push elt reverse))))
```

- Define a local `reverse` variable, bound to NIL by default (you could set it to `'()`, this is sometimes preferred).
- Use `DOLIST` to iterate over a list and perform side-effects; the third argument is the return value; here you can put the `reverse` variable where we accumulate the reversed list.
- For each element `elt`, push it in front of `reverse`; if you want to avoid `push` for learning purposes, use `(setf reverse (cons elt reverse))`.

Common Lisp is multi-paradigm and favors pragmatic solutions: sometimes a loop is more natural or more efficient, and there is no reason to force yourself to adopt a functional style.

### Functional implementation

However, lists provide a natural inductive structure: recursive approaches may be more appropriate in some cases.
If you wanted to use a functional style to compute reverse, be aware that tail-call optimization, though commonly available, is not required by the language specification (it depends on your implementation capabilities and compiler options).

With default settings, SBCL eliminates calls in tail positions and would eliminate the risk of stack overflows with large inputs. But there are other possible ways to obtain bad algorithmic complexities (and wasteful code) if you are not careful.
The following is what I'd use to define the combination of union and reverse; in particular, I prefer to define a local function with `labels` to avoid calling `new-union` with a dummy nil parameter. Also, I iterate the list resulting from the union only once.

```
(defun new-union (l1 l2)
  (labels ((rev (list acc)
             (etypecase list
               (null acc)
               (cons (rev (rest list)
                          (cons (first list) acc))))))
    (rev (union l1 l2) nil)))
```

### Trace

```
  0: (NEW-UNION (A B C) (D E F))
    1: (UNION (A B C) (D E F))
    1: UNION returned (C B A D E F)
    1: (REV (C B A D E F) NIL)
      2: (REV (B A D E F) (C))
        3: (REV (A D E F) (B C))
          4: (REV (D E F) (A B C))
            5: (REV (E F) (D A B C))
              6: (REV (F) (E D A B C))
                7: (REV NIL (F E D A B C))
                7: REV returned (F E D A B C)
              6: REV returned (F E D A B C)
            5: REV returned (F E D A B C)
          4: REV returned (F E D A B C)
        3: REV returned (F E D A B C)
      2: REV returned (F E D A B C)
    1: REV returned (F E D A B C)
  0: NEW-UNION returned (F E D A B C)
```

### Remark

It is quite surprising to reverse the result of [`union`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_unionc.htm), when the union is supposed to operate on unordered sets: *the order of elements in the result do not have to reflect the ordering of list-1 or list-2 in any way.* Sets are unordered collections having no duplicates; if your input lists already represent sets, as hinted by the name of the function (`new-union`), then it makes no sense to remove duplicates or expect the order to be meaningful.

If, instead, the input lists represents sequences of values, then the order matters; feel free to use `append` or `concatenate` in combination with `remove-duplicates`, but note that the latter will remove elements in front of the list by default:

```
(remove-duplicates (concatenate 'list '(4 5 6) '(2 3 4)))
=> (5 6 2 3 4)
```

You may want to use `:from-end t` instead.

Comment: It looks like your reverse function doesn't actually reverse...it shuffles

Answer (score -1):

Ok...I think you want to take two lists, combine them together, remove duplicates, and then reverse them.

Your biggest problem is that you're using loops instead of recursion. LISP was born to do list processing using recursion. It's far more natural.

Below is a very simple example of how to do that:

```
(defvar l1 '(a b c))      ;first list
(defvar l2 '(d e f))      ;second list

(defun my-reverse (a b)   ;a and b are lists
  "combines a and b into lst, removes duplicates, and reverses using recursion"
  (let ((lst (remove-duplicates (append a b))))   
    (if (> (length lst) 0)
        (append (last lst) (my-reverse nil (butlast lst)))
        nil)))
```

Sample Run compiled in SLIME using SBCL

```
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.010                                                                                                                                    
CL-USER> l1 ;; verify l1 variable
(A B C)                                                                                                                                                                  
CL-USER> l2 ;; verify l2 variable
(D E F)                                                                                                                                                                  
CL-USER> (append l1 l2) ;; append l1 and l2
(A B C D E F)                                                                                                                                                            
CL-USER> (my-reverse l1 l2) ;; reverse l1 and l2
(F E D C B A)
```

Comment: I don't see a requirement for removing duplicates in the question.

Comment: OP used union in his code example and explanation. Union removes duplicates so I removed duplicates in my solution.

Comment: Not required by the spec: *If either list-1 or list-2 has duplicate entries within it, the redundant entries might or might not appear in the result.* (http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_unionc.htm)

Comment: OP didn't ask about Common Lisp lacunae. Union comes out of set theory and sets don't contain duplicates. The use of set theory suggested to me that OP wanted to remove duplicates.

Comment: Yeah. I thought unions handle duplicates implicitly. So went ahead with that.  Also, Thanks for the tip of working on recursion functions. I'm more accustomed to loops coming from oops programming.

Comment: @lamo_738 I hear you. Imperative languages stress loops over recursion--although most of them have recursion in some form--so it's natural to feel more at home with iteration. I feel the opposite in Lisp: recursion feels more natural and looping feels more awkward. Also, my answer is wordier than it needs to be, but I wanted it to be clear rather than pithy so you could dissect it.

Comment: @clay. Thank you for parsing the whole thing for me. will keep it in mind while doing further lisp programs.